# asp.net listview sorting and manual data binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, sorting, data-binding

I am having a bit of a strange issue.
I have a ListView which I sort in ASC/DESC order by clicking the listview header, using the method below, now the thing is that works perfectly when I have an ObjectDataSource defined and attach that to the ListView.

Now if I just use manual binding using

```
listview.DataSource = GetListViewContent();
listview.DataBind();
```

the sorting no longer works. I have tried re-binding in the sort method but still it does not work. Am I missing something?

```
protected void lvFullReport_Sorting(object sender, ListViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        Control me = (Control)sender,
           headerRow = me.FindControl("headerRow");

         //Assume that the "header row" control's "control collection" just contains "th"-like control,
         //whose type is exactly "HtmlTableCell" . While we just utilize its properties in the "HtmlControl" level
         //so we cast them as "HtmlControl".
         //What's more , as for these "th" controls , just those who contains an "IButtonControl" ( sorting triggers)
         //are really needed.


        foreach (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl sortCell in headerRow.Controls.Cast<System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl>()
            .Where(th => th.Controls.OfType<IButtonControl>().Any()))
        {
              //Get out the "only" sorting-Button Control ,
              //for that in a "th" those empty space or literal text area are treated as "Literal Control" ,
              //"literal" fills whole space of "th".

            IButtonControl btnSortField = sortCell.Controls.OfType<IButtonControl>().Single();

            if (btnSortField.CommandArgument == e.SortExpression)
                sortCell.Attributes["class"] = e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "up" : "down";
            else
                if (sortCell.Attributes["class"] != null) sortCell.Attributes.Remove("class");
        }

        DisplayChart();
    }
```

GetListViewContent() is the source for manual and auto sources and for display purposes both work to show the data; but sorting only works in the auto.

Comment: Why not try this  http://beckelman.net/2008/10/16/client-side-aspnet-listview-sorting-via-jquery-tablesorter-plugin-demo/

Comment: @MMLK, the live demo in the link you provided does not work. It returns 500 server error.

Comment: Thanks for the link but the code I have is actually working I'm sure I'm just missing something very basic to fix the manual binding. I am a bit pressed for time to implement another solution.

Comment: can you confirm your TemplateFields  have SortExpression set?

Comment: Yes they do, hence the reason it works when not manually binding the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to rebind sorted data. So maybe you should consider implementig your method this way:

`GetListViewContent(SortDirection sortDir)`;

Answer (score 0):

I too was always getting e.SortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending when using an object data source. I found the following helpful post:
http://www.codedigest.com/articles/aspnet/412_sorting_in_aspnet_listview_control_-_binding_in_codebehind.aspx

Which lead me to the following solution to store the SortExpression in ViewState and then override e.SortDirection with the correct value.

```
protected void ListView_Sorting(object sender, ListViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    // Override sort direction (since it's always ascending when 
    // we're using an object data source)
    e.SortDirection = GetListViewSortDirection(e.SortExpression);

    // Rebind data
    ProductListView.DataSource = 
        GetListViewContent(e.SortExpression, e.SortDirection);
    ProductListView.DataBind();
}

private SortDirection GetListViewSortDirection(string sortExpression)
{
    // Store sort expression in viewstate
    SortDirection listViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
    if (ViewState["SortExpression"] != null 
        && ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString() == sortExpression)
    {
        ViewState["SortExpression"] = null;
        listViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewState["SortExpression"] = sortExpression;
    }

    return listViewSortDirection;
}
```